# Square root of a mod n

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $n = pq$, where $p = 13710221545914561761$ and $q = 11066328760152681859$ are both primes.
Find the (two) square roots of $1 \mod n$ that are not  $\pm1\mod n$. Let the square roots be $a_1\mod n$ and $a_2 \mod n$, with $a_1,a_2$ element of $\{0,n-1\}$ and $a_1 > a_2$, find $a_1$.

**Solution.** 
Begin with the congruence with the largest modulus, Rewrite this congruence as an equivalent equation:
                    $$x=13710221545914561761 j + 1$$

Substitute this expression for $x$ into the congruence with the next largest modulus:

$$x\equiv 1\mod 11066328760152681859$$
$$\Rightarrow 13710221545914561761 j + 1 \equiv 1\mod 11066328760152681859$$

Comment: square roots $\pmod n$ are also square roots $\pmod p$ and $\pmod q$, so...

Comment: can you solve i am stuck in it

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands)  for mathematical notations.

Comment: @ramchauhan I already hinted you something. Edit the question and write what you've tried to do.

Comment: how to solve congruence after that @Exodd

Comment: This is a question from Bose Center (Kolkata) cryptology internship etrance contest. The contest is on-going. I apogize for the inconvenience to the unsuspecting parties. I have contacted the people at Bose Center. They are aware of the leaks, and have prepared countermeasures.